# Google Analytics Not Tracking Sub Domain

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, analytics, tracking

I have a website where I plan on setting up a few sub domains ( Which I want to be kept completely sepperate ) and I've set up an sepperate tracking code for each one.

I've set my default domain to `sub.mydomain.com` and been given the tracking code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-53076472-2', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

However when I run the page my analytics still show `0 Online`.  When I run the source code the correct JS tracking code is shown - What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

By Default,GA tracks for tld's , you need to change the code to track subdomain. 
ga('create', 'UA-53076472-2', 'auto'); - This only tracks the top level domain.
Replace this line with the below mentioned code...and Check ...

Hope it works for you..
    ga('create', 'UA-53076472-2', {'cookieDomain': 'mydomain.com'}); /* test for subdomain
    _gaq.push([‘_setAccount’, 'UA-53076472-2']);
    _gaq.push([‘_setDomainName’, ‘mydomain.com’]);
    _gaq.push([‘_addIgnoredRef’, 'mydomain.com']);
    ga('require', 'displayfeatures'); //display properties
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    ga('send', 'pageview');

Thanks,
jaysaysin@dccm